# What to call a person with whom you spend time just because?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phrase-requests

What to call a person with whom you spend time not because you like them but because you haven't found anyone better?

**EDIT**: I am asking more about a romantic kind of relationship than mere companionship, and about a situation when one person kind of uses another.

Comment: Ugh.  This question is only *mildly* repugnant. /s  How about [victim?](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/victim)

Comment: Companion? At least for people you meet during travels and travel with them just because they go in the same direction you use this.

Comment: @Lumberjack it's just about vocabulary.

Comment: @skymninge no, i am asking more about romantic kind of relationship

Comment: Why would you be in a relationship with someone you don't like, though? It's better to be single!

Comment: @mikhailcazi hahah)) thank you but i am asking not because i need advice on relationship. ijust wanna know the right world for this kind of person in English

Comment: I still think victim is appropriate.  Definition 2 as cited above: Victim - "a person who is cheated or fooled by someone else."

Comment: Squatting assets.

Comment: Is this a mutual arrangement, or is the other person "in love" so to speak?

Comment: @Mari-LouA it's not a mutual arrangement

Comment: Dunno what I'd call *them* but I have some ideas about what to call *you*.

Comment: @JeffSahol so what?

Comment: @OlgaMano forgot the smilely on that one :)

Answer (score 12):

I'll throw down on this one. Let's say that anyone who is dating is looking for "Mr. Right", or "Ms. Right". But they haven't found them yet. The person they date while waiting may be referred to as "[Mr. Right Now](http://www.metrolyrics.com/mr-right-now-lyrics-pitbull.html)" (or "Ms. Right Now").

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest that you are friends with (or dating) that person *[by default](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/default)*:

> a selection made usually automatically or without active consideration due to lack of a viable alternative

I'll also point out that Urban Dictionary includes the formulation "*[default friend](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=default%20friend)*", which may be understood by some listeners: it's grammatically sound, although sounds somewhat unusual to my ear. The formulation "*boyfriend/girlfriend by default*" or "*we are friends by default*" is likely to be more widely and readily understood.

Answer (score 3):

You might figuratively use the term **[consolation prize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consolation-prize?q=consolation%20prize)**

> a prize given to a competitor who just fails to win or who has come last

You also might consider **[booby prize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/booby-prize?q=booby%20prize)**

> a prize given as a joke to the person who is last in a race or competition

This latter choice seems appropriate in light of the definition of *[booby](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/booby?q=booby)*

> a stupid person

Consider the advice of Crosby, Stills, and Nash:

*If you can't be with the one you love, honey, love the one you're with.*

The unasked question is what do you call the person who is settling for the second-rate companionship. Perhaps **user**?

Comment: what do you mean by "settling for the second-rate companionship"?

Comment: *Second-rate* means of a lesser quality, since your speaker finds the current companion and relationship not *first-rate*, meaning of the highest quality.

Answer (score 3):

**FWB** or **Friend With Benefits**

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fwb), this is the #1 definition:

> casual relationship implying no committment, but involving companionship (the friends bit) and some sort of physical element like making out, sex, baseball (the benefits). although rumored to be a myth, absolutely possible.

also from Urban Dictionary, the #2 definition is

> When two people aren't officially going out but have sex anyway. Compare with f**k buddy.

I always understood it to be the second definition, but hipper people say otherwise.

Comment: BFW is more about a situation when both agree on this kind of relationship. i am asking more about a situstion when one person kind of uses another.

Answer (score 2):

The word I would use is "place holder." Someone who is occupying a "place" while you wait for a "real" candidate.

An even less-kind word is "stopgap."

Answer (score 1):

Here are the names I've heard these relationships referred to:

**"rebounder"** - the next person you date after a break-up with another person

**"booty call"** - casual, consensual sex, usually at the end of the evening, sometimes after a real date has been dropped off

**"F*ck-buddy"** - like "booty call" but usually you're also friends with this person

Comment: It depends on the nature of the relationship. All of these could be used in a romantic/sexual context, but there are other kinds of (quite different) relationships that would still fall under the wide umbrella of the O.P.'s question. For example, I might sit and eat lunch with Sam every day in the company cafeteria, but not so much because I'm very fond of Sam; rather, it's because all my closer associates eat elsewhere, like down the street, or at their desk. (Not meant to be a critique of your answer, but, with the limited information provided, we can interpret the question in several ways.)

Comment: P.S. I just noticed the exchange in the comments between @skymninge and the O.P., so I guess my comment doesn't really apply. But I'll leave it here as an exhortation to others: avoid asking questions with skimpy details; also, it's best to  clarify with edits, not comments.

Comment: @english_learner - Welcome aboard. No need to say sorry. Also, you probably want to use "I" instead of "i" – this is a friendly bunch, but people take their English _very_ seriously here. :^) Also, there's another Stack Exchange site that might interest you: [ell.se]. (They take English seriously there, too, but that's a good place for those learning English to ask questions. You can read more [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).)